# How to configure apache2 vhosts for difference www director on mac 10.11

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

I want to configure vhost for difference from www as below configure but it not work it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin com.dev
    DocumentRoot "Applications/AMPPS/www/com/public"
    ServerName com.dev
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/com.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/com.dev-access_log" common
 </VirtualHost>
```

This one I have try to another director but it still go to localhost only

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin com.dev
    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/web/com/public"
    ServerName com.dev
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/com.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/com.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Host
127.0.0.1 com.dev

Comment: two vhosts with the same name? Exactly how do you expect Apache to be able to figure out WHAT site someone wants if they come to `http://com.dev`?

Comment: no I jst testing actualy I create only one and it always go to localhost/ only